# Unable to vertically align text inside a TD

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically center text inside my `TD`s.

I have tried the following but I'm unable to achieve desired results.

```
<table class="student_table">
    <tr>
        <th class="class_box" colspan="4">Batch 2012</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="batch_header">
        <td> Hi </td> <!--Have to center this-->
        <td> Hi </td>
        <td> Hi </td>
        <td> Hi </td>
    </tr>

.batch_header{
    width: 140px;
    float: left;
}
.batch_header td{
    width:30px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:#EEE;
    margin:0px;
    padding:2.5px;
    border:0px;
    float:left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: smaller;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; <!-- < This is not working-->
}
```

Comment: there is no need of  float: left; i think....

Comment: check this it is working : http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_vertical-align

Comment: Take a look to my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Remove

```
float:left;
```

from

```
.batch_header td{ }
```

```css
.batch_header{
    width: 140px;
    float: left;
}
.batch_header td{
    width:30px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:#EEE;
    margin:0px;
    padding:2.5px;
    border:0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: smaller;
    text-align:center;    
    vertical-align: middle; <!-- < This is not working-->
}
```

```html
<table class="student_table" border = 1>
    <tr>
        <th class="class_box" colspan="4">Batch 2012</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="batch_header">
        <td> Hi </td> <!--Have to center this-->
        <td> Hi </td>
        <td> Hi </td>
        <td> Hi </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s96fwhkv/1/)

Note: I have given border to table for visibility purpose.

Update:

Please see [Demo2 Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsq7x01c/1/)

Just Added `line-height: 1.9;` in CSS

Comment: I need to do it with it `float:left;`. Without it i get some extra space around cells however all padding, margin, spacing is 0 but still. to solve this i have added float:left. I have added it for some layout requirements. Is there a way i can achieve my goal with this?

Comment: @Maven `table { border-collapse: collapse}`

Comment: tried `border-collapse: collapse` and `border-spacing: 0px;` still a space is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you take out the `display: inline-block;` and `float: left;` lines, it will look the way you want.

Comment: yes it does. but after removing `float: left;` i get some extra space on the right of cells. Thats why i was using `float: left;`. Any idea what that space might be?

Comment: I'm not seeing any horizontal re-alignment in Chrome when I remove the float. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

No CSS needed because you are using tables and tables own sometimes

Here is the table for you

```
<table width="200">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle">Batch 2012</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"> Hi </td> 
        <td align="center" valign="middle"> Hi </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"> Hi </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"> Hi </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is a demo for you

https://jsfiddle.net/1zhdLb55/1/