# How to make TDs inside a table of equal width

Tags: html, css

I have a following layout. I want all the `TD`s of equal width and extra space around them.

If I use `float:left;` over TDs all get equally sized but then `vertical-align: middle;` stops working.

Is there a way I can do it without using `float:left;`?

```html
<table class="student_table">
    <tr>
        <th class="class_box" colspan="4">Batch 2012</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="batch_header">
        <td> Hi </td> <!--Have to center this-->
        <td> Hi </td>
        <td> Hi </td>
        <td> Hi </td>
    </tr>
```

```css
.batch_header{
    width: 245px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.batch_header td{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#EEE;
    margin:0px;
    padding:2.5px;
    border:0px;
    <!-- float:left; --> <!-- < equally sized with this but not vertically aligned is not working-->
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: smaller;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle; <!-- < This is not working-->
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to float a `<td>` tag. Why don't you just use `width: nnpx`?

Comment: if you have a static number of columns just use `width:25 %;`

Comment: Same question has been posted twice.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871696/unable-to-vertically-align-text-inside-a-td]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No CSS needed because you are using tables and tables own sometimes

Here is the table for you

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Batch 2012</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#666666" style="width:100px; margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;"> Hi </td> 
    <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#666666" style="width:100px; margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;"> Hi </td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#666666" style="width:100px; margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;"> Hi </td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#666666" style="width:100px; margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;"> Hi </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is a updated demo for you

https://jsfiddle.net/1zhdLb55/3/

EDIT
If you now dont want fixed width just delete the width:100px; and it will still give you space on left and right. If you dont want borders just add border:0 cellspacing:0 etc

Comment: I am sure it did worked so please mark the question as correct so we show the CSS DIVS guys with complex CSS code that tables still rule in this world and will keep ruling forever

Comment: Thankyou. But my this questions is how to make TDs of equal width without using float not about aligning text inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height: 1.9;` to `.batch_header td{}`

```css
.batch_header{
    width: 140px;
    float: left;
}
.batch_header td{
    width:30px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:#EEE;
    margin:0px auto;
    float:left;
    padding:2.5px;
    border:0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: smaller;
    text-align:center;    
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1.9;
}
```

```html
<table class="student_table" border = 1>
    <tr>
        <th class="class_box" colspan="4">Batch 2012</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="batch_header">
        <td> Hi </td> <!--Have to center this-->
        <td> Hi </td>
        <td> Hi </td>
        <td> Hi </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsq7x01c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

using only HTML

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <th colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle">Batch 2012</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"> Hi </td> 
    <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"> Hi </td>
    <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"> Hi </td>
    <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"> Hi </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the style: `table-layout:fixed` to your table css style (.student_table) and make sure the table has a set width.  Remove the `float:left` and the td width (it will calculate equal width to all cells) and remove the `display: inline-block` on the `<tr>` tag.